# Nested directive link function not called, controller not acknowledged

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I apologise in advance: there are a sea of 'mah directive link function isn't called!' functions in SO, but none of the answers applied to me.

I have a directive sgMapHeader nested inside another directive, sgMap. sgMapHeader is optional, so I append it and compile at sgMap's link time. The two share a controller. [Here is a highly reduced JSBin.](http://jsbin.com/keyevu/edit?html,js)

In a perfect world, I would expect two things:

1. The inner directive's link function would be called and 'hi there' would be logged.
2. If I clicked on the 'hi there' text, 'hold' would be logged.

Unfortunately, neither happens. I tried various scales of scope but nothing improved. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sgMapCtrl** is not defined

```
controllerAs:'sgMapCtrl',
```

in your sgMap directive

This code works well for me :

**EDIT**

```
angular.module('map.directive', [])
.directive('sgMap', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        replace: false,
        template: '<section class="md-whitespace-2"></section>',
        scope: {
            header: '=header',                 // Whether to show the header. (bool)
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        controllerAs:'sgMapCtrl',
        controller: [function() {
            this.changeAction = function(action) {
                console.log(action);
            };
        }],
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // Add header?
            if (scope.header) {

                $compile('<sg-map-header></sg-map-header>')(scope, function(cloned, scope) {
                    element.append(cloned);
                });
            }
        }
    };
}])
.directive('sgMapHeader', [function() {
    'use strict';

    return {
        replace: false,
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^sgMap',
        scope: false,
        template: '<div ng-click="sgMapCtrl.changeAction(\'hold\')">hi there</div>',
        link: ['$scope', 'sgMapCtrl', function($scope, sgMapCtrl) {
            sgMapCtrl.changeAction('<div>hi there</div>');
        }]
    };
}]);

angular.module('app', ['map.directive']);
```

Comment: This is true, and may be of relevance later, but since link() is never called, I could call it `stinkyCheesecake` and not get a null reference error.

Comment: Oh, I see, the controller object needs to be present in ng-click. Didn't expect that. So, great, the click action works! Thanks. The link function still isn't getting called, though.

Comment: Well, I was hoping someone else would have a crack at the remaining question, but then you would have to fight him to the death for the accepted answer...nah. You can have it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Append to the DOM first, and then compile.

```
        // Add header?
        if (scope.header) {
            var $header = angular.element('<sg-map-header></sg-map-header>');
            element.append($header);
            $compile($header)(scope);
        }
```

sgMapDirective has to be a child of sgMap at *time* of compiling. Otherwise when the compile searches the parent elements of sgMapDirective it doesn't find anything, because it only exists in memory. Not the DOM.

Comment: Sorry, I should have indicated this was the first thing I tried. [This is why I stuck with the current approach.](http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/nested-recursive-directives-in-angular/#comment-991048825) TL;DR: Apparently I would be compiling twice with your approach. I'm totally uninformed, so feel free to call BS on that.